# Connecting LED to RO pin of RS485 Transceiver

Tags: led, communication, signal, rs485, receiver

I am using [this RS485 transceiver](http://focus.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65176b.pdf) in a circuit of mine and I'd like to place a tiny 0805 LED in series with a 1k resistor coming off of the RO (receiving) pin.  I'm hoping this would result in flashing of the LED.  However, since I don't have a ton of experience with RS485 transceivers, I'm not sure this will work.  Will it cause any issues with communication?  Will it look right? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted, typical baud rates will flash the LED at rates which are invisible to the eye.

The visual effect that you want can be obtained by adding either some form of triggered oscillator or some form of "monostable" or (most elegantly) by using a microcontroller to control the flashing and decision making.

A single Schmitt trigger gate in a tiny package would do the job. Probably a SOT23-6 package.

While using a microcontroller may seem like bizarre overkill (and probably is :-) ) it also allows a minimum parts count solution, small size, great flexibility, addition of other features if desired AND immense Cool! value.

A device such as a [PIC10F200 in stock at digikey for 56 cents in 1's](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41239D.pdf) would do your job with NO extra parts apart from the LED, or perhaps one resistor if you wanted to be "proper". I chose that for it's lowest cost in 1's in a small package - but you can get cheaper.

If this is a one off job there will be people willing to write a program for you for free AND program you a chip, just for the sheer joy of the stupidity of such overkill.

Packages include DFN (2mmj x 3mm leadless smd), SOT23-6 (2.3 x 3.1mm worst case outside leads) and DIP.

**Schmitt trigger inverter based flasher:**

The diagram below is from fig 14 in [74HC14 data sheet here](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT14.pdf)

[image: Oscillator]

This will drive an LED or a second gate can be used as a buffer.

To gate this on and off  a diode is connected to the gate input.

- [Gate package 74HC14](http://ics.nxp.com/products/hc/datasheet/74hc1g14.74hct1g14.pdf) or equivalent.
- Resistor R gate_in to gate_out (eg pin 2 to pin3) say 100k
- Capacitor gate in to ground - say 1 uF ceramic
- Diode RS485 line to gate in (polarity tbd - see below)
- LED with series resistor from gate out either to Vcc or ground with appropriate polarity OT
- gate_out to gate2_in. gate2_out to drive LED via series R as before. Gate 2 here acts as a buffer.

This will oscillate at ABOUT 10 Hz with values given  (12.5 Hz according to their formula) when the diode is reverse biased. It will stop oscillating when the diode conducts. Connect diode to RS485 line with connection and polarity to suit.

The state that the gate is "stalled" in controls whether the LED is on or off when not flashing.

---

Note to compulsive editors: anyone who wants to add an enabling diode and LED with series R is welcome.

Comment: When you edit a post you have a small toolbar above the edit box. One of the icons is to insert an image. You get a popup where you can give the image's location either on your computer or on the 'Net. HTH

Comment: BTW, this kind of images screams for a PNG format, JPG is more for photographs.

Answer (score 2):

If the baud rate is above a few hundred hertz, the LED flashing will be indiscernible to the human eye - it will merely appear dimmer.

It's usually better to buffer the signal with an opamp, then use the buffered signal for 'other' purposes (like driving an LED) so that whatever else is connected to the receive line isn't influenced by the current drawn by the LED (I/O usually isn't stiff).

Again, unless you're operating e-x-t-r-e-m-e-l-y s-l-o-w-l-y you won't see any flashing.

Answer (score 2):

Like others already said you won't see the LED blink, because it blinks too fast for your eyes. The LED will just appear to light more dim.
That said, if you still want to connect the LED to the receiver's output, the datasheet shows the Schottky totem-pole output and the current sink/source values that can be expected for this: source 0.4mA, sink 8mA. So you'll have to sink the current. To get a decent light level from a LED at 8mA you need a high-efficiency LED, especially since, like I said, it will appear more dim due to the "blinking".

I would try something else. Can't the microcontroller blink a LED as it receives data from the bus?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way without programming is to stick a one-shot on there. A [74HC123](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT123.pdf) has two independent units in one chip, so you could put indicators on both send and receive data. If you don't mind SMD there are single unit chips available. too.

[image]

A positive-going edge on nB or a negative-going edge on n/A will trigger the multivibrator and n/Q will go low for about 0.45RC (it varies a bit by type).   So if you pick Cext = 1uF and Rext = 330K you'll get about a 150ms pulse, which is easy to see. If the edges occur very frequently the pulse will be retriggered and the output will stay low.

So you tie n/RD high, tie n/A low, and connect nB to your data output. The LED goes from n/Q to Vdd with a suitable resistor in series. As to n/Q you can leave it open.