# How would I go about converting a change in capacitance into a voltage?

Tags: capacitor, converter

Just starting out with electronics here as a physics student- I appreciate the help!

In a simple LCR circuit with a variable capacitor, how would I go about detecting the change in capacitance and converting that change into a measurable voltage signal? What kind of circuit/ components will I need?

Comment: \$Q=CV\$ is the defining equation of a capacitor. If you keep \$Q\$ constant (by not letting any current flow in or out of the capacitor) while adjusting \$C\$, then \$V\$ will have to change to compensate. Obviously this will be easier to do if you're talking about varying the capacitance by mechanically adjusting a couple of plates than if you're talking about a varicap diode.

Comment: Can the capacitor be isolated, or is it required to remain a part of your "simple LCR" circuit?

Comment: @The Photon I am indeed talking about a plate capacitor

@W5VO♦ It will remain part of the circuit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way that I can think of is using that capacitor in an oscillator circuit. Unless your capacitor is very small in value (less than 100 pF) you usually do not need to use an inductor to use that capacitor in an oscillator. An oscillator can also be made with an RC circuit, this is used in the 555 timer chip.

The frequency of oscillation would change as the capacitor changes value. Then you only need to measure the frequency of oscillation which is is often as easy as counting pulses for a certain time (like 1 second) and then displaying how many cycles were counted.

Please state between what values your capacitor will vary so we can give you more practical advise in the direction of a usable solution.

Comment: The capacitance will be very small, on the order of 10-100 pF, if that is helpful?

Comment: RC oscillator should work even with 10-100 pF capacitor. Not the standard 555 timer, of course; probably 74HC14 or 74AC14 based oscillator would be OK.

Comment: You're in luck, I found an answer to another question showing how to make an oscillator with the 74HC14: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17267/connecting-led-to-ro-pin-of-rs485-transceiver  The 74HC14 contains 6 individual schmitt-trigger inverters. You only need one of those, a resistor and your capacitor to build an oscillator. There is no easier way to do this as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

With a capacitance of 10pF to 100pF, the easiest thing may be to make a simple filter and measure the output:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJKEup.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For 10pF, the resistor and capacitor will have equal voltages (at \$\frac {V_s} {\sqrt (2)}\$) at 159kHz and for 100pF it will be at 15.9kHz. Change the value of the capacitor and then adjust the input frequency such that \$V_{out}\$ = \$0.0707V_s\$.

You could measure both voltages and simply change the frequency until each are equal.

The capacitance at this new frequency is easily definable.

As \$ X_c = \frac {1} {2\pi f c}\$ we can rearrange so that the capacitance must be \$C =  \frac {1} {2\pi f 100k}\$ (because for equal voltages, the capacitive reactance and the resistance must be equal and I used 100k for the resistor).

An interesting way to watch the phase (and therefore relative voltages) is by using a [lissajous figure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6nGiBzGLD8)

Comment: This is not a very practical way of determining the value of the capacitor as you need some additional equipment to measure Vs and Vmeasure over frequency. The most practical way using this is if you have a network analyzer, but these cost many thousands of dollars.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want a DC like voltage refrence that changes based on the capacitor's current value, on something of the realtime-continuous order, and not an offline capacitance tester

I would try using a PWM controler. Some use an external RC circut to set the switching frequency. Which of course is useless in a DC world.  But the C of the RC circut also changes the Dead Time of the output. So asuming you have a steady duty cycle feed to the controller(like 100%). A changing dead time duration would effectively change your output Duty Cycle.

The PWM signal would read as DC voltage level, who's value is based on the output PWM's duty cycle.

So,  Change in capacitance -> change in Dead Time -> change in efective output duty cycle -> chang in DC voltage value.

This has elemets of RC circuts, and frequncy, however unlike the other current answers this soultion doesn't need to worry about them, or any time based mesurements.

Might not be the best part, but as an example look at LT1241